# Live Reloading not working on iOS device after removing Expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

Live Reloading works on simulator but not my physical device. This has been the case since I've removed expo and it's packages completely from my project. Following a few tutorials I revised my Babel config to use this package (also installed via yarn):

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  };
};
```

I also added a main.jsbundle file to my project and added the command to populate it:

```
yarn react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

The only thing that appears when the app's done install is a black bar above the app saying:

```
Connect to metro to develop javascript react native
```

**Things to Note:**

- My phone is connected to the same network as my M1 Mac
- Entering the IP and port manually in the test app doesn't seem to work either
- Cleaning the build, deleting/reinstalling the app from my phone, and restarting Xcode + Mac doesn't work
- My build scheme is set to "Debug" and **NOT** set to "Release"

**React Version:**  0.64.0